# AWS EC2- Synching source code files with S3 - is it a proper approach?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

On an app server in which a few source files change frequently, Is the following approach recommended?

Use a cron job with S3tools to sync the source files with S3 private bucket (every 15 mins for example).

On server start up - Use user data script to sync with the sources bucket to retrieve the latest sources.

Advantages:
1. No need to attach EBS for app server just to save a few files
2. Similar setup to all app servers
3. Sources automatically backed up.
4. As a byproduct, distributes code to multiple app servers automatically.

Disadvantages:
keeping source code on S3
other?

What do you think about this methodology? Is this the right way to use EC2 when source code change frequently (a few times a day) please recommend the best approach to run EC2 instances where sources change often.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're better off using a proper source code repository, like Subversion or Git, rather than storing the source files on S3.  That way you can have a central location for the source files while avoiding the update consistency problems that kdgregory mentioned.

You can put the source repository on one of your own servers outside of EC2, or host it on an EC2 instance (make sure the repository files are on an EBS volume in the latter case).

Comment: I don't want to involve an external server in the setup. I want to have a simple reliable setup in which the system automatically gets back in shape if something happens. Adding an external server lose the charm of simplicity and expose the system to failure of one more provider.

Comment: +1 for using source control, rather than just overwriting files in S3. What if you want to roll back to a previous version? Personally, I don't think storing the source code in a private git repository (hosted on github, say) has a greater chance of failure than storing it in an s3 bucket. Neither service is going to go down anytime soon, and if they do, you'll certainly know about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be running a large number of EC2 instances, then it will be less effort to have them sync themselves from a central location (ie, you sync to private bucket, app-servers sync from that bucket).

HOWEVER, recognize that updates to an S3 bucket are atomic only at the object level, and more importantly, are not guaranteed to be immediately consistent (although I recall seeing a recent note that the us-west endpoint does offer read-after-write consistency).

This means that your app-servers may load a set of new files that are internally inconsistent -- some will be old, some will be new. If this is a problem for you, then you should implement a scheme that uploads directly to the app-servers, and ensures changeset consistency (perhaps by uploading to a temporary directory that is then renamed).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not concerned because of read after write consistency. the writes to S3 will happen only after code file changes during cron run so its not something that will happen in the same time the server restarts and requires to sync the sources back to the server.

What is the best practice to achieve source code persistence in an app server on EC2?